# my nikon not showing in autofocus

Tags: nikon-d5000

my niece who lives in another state has the D5000, as do I. Her camera has stopped auto-focusing. 
I've tried troubleshooting over the phone but the focusing problem continues. Here are the settings and what we tried so far:

1. made sure the lens' A/M switch is set to 'A'
2. Focus mode is set to AF-A
3. 18-55 VR. I had her switch lenses but still no auto-focus
4. tried different Auto Focus area modes (single, dynamic, auto-area).

The battery is charged. She can see the focus points in the optical viewfinder light up in red.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Does the focus confirm light come on in the viewfinder when manually focused? (marked 6 on here: http://www.imaging-resource.com/PRODS/D5000/D5000VIEWFINDER.HTM)

Comment: If this error happens with multiple lenses, then either the lens contacts of the camera body got dirty, or the body is malfunctioning. Check for pieces of lint or dirt or dust, or whatever on the contacts.

Answer (score 0):

As outlined by @TFuto:

> If this error happens with multiple lenses, then either the lens contacts of the camera body got dirty, or the body is malfunctioning. Check for pieces of lint or dirt or dust, or whatever on the contacts.